# Catalogue / Product Database Design

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, database-design

As I have looked all over for an answer to my question and found nothing of use, I can only assume a) I can't use Google b) I'm the only one stupid enough to not know the answer off my own back.... So would be greatful for any advice or support on this.

Basically I'm setting up a basic e-commerce site. I have the standard products, customers, orders, orderdetails, addresses, and cart tables in place.

What I'm struggling to envisage is how to incorporate cataloguing into my design. There will be hundreds of products and downs of account but not all the products will be available to each account/customer. One customer may only have 4 products in their catalogue to choose from but another may have 50.  Would merely creating a seperate catalogue for each customer (CatalogueID against Account ID), at the risk of repeating data, be my only answer?

Hope this makes sense.

Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You probably should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to get any answers around here. More specifically, your question is too broad. Try to solve the issues you've mentioned, and if you still need help - focus your question(s) and attach your attempts. Good luck!

Comment: Hi GalAbra. I hope you're well. My questions is merely how do I incorporate cataloguing in my products database where each customer has a different catalogue?

Comment: So can two different customers buy the same widget? If so, then create a master catalogue table with a bridging table in between (which has customerid and itemid in it). If not then create a master catalogue table with a customer id in it. That's a general answer to a general question. This is a data modelling question which depends on the realtionships between entities

Comment: Big Nick, Thank you soo much for your reply. Really appreciate it!  Yes, more than one customer can order a particular product but each customer has a virtual catalogue if you like, as in they can only order particular products from the hundreds of items available.  I did think of your solution at the very beginning but felt it wouldn't be that simple. :-) So to recap, keep my products catalogue with the 720 items it contains and my customers database which has 14 accounts but in the middle of both have say a catalogue table with the Customerid against the productid on a one to one basis?

Comment: Yes - totally. I do suggest you add another identity int field that is the primary key of the table, _and_ also add a unique constraint on customerid / productid to ensure it is always unique

Comment: Hey Nick, "Yes - totally. I do suggest you add another identity int field that is the primary key of the table" which table? Cheers.

Comment: Cheers again, Nick. Worked like a dream...'Sweet as a nut!'